# How do I manipulate requests and response headers in AWS Api Gatway using Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, proxy, aws-api-gateway

I want to create an API Gateway HTTP integration (reverse proxy) but manipulate the header and response headers.

I know that I can use **template mappings** but this only supports very simple replace functionality.

For my project I need to do a database lookup to fill in a certain request header. Ideally a Lambda function would do this but I can not see a way to use a Lambda function to manipulate headers in combination with the HTTP integration.

The only other option I see is to use Lambda integration and create a whole reverse proxy integration myself in this Lambda. I would like to avoid this.

Any options someone can think off?

Answer (score 1):

You can front your API gateway with CloudFront. This allows you to manipulate http requests before they reach your API through [CloudFront function](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/) or [lambda@edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-functions.html). Both of them can be lambda functions.